# Eclipse config project to run child project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, configuration

I have two project in eclipse one is a library I have written and the other is a app for android that uses the lib. Everything is working fine for one exception when I'm changing the code for the lib and tries to build I of course get a error saying that you can't run a library. So what i want to know is it possible to config eclipse to build the child project (the project using the lib) to be ran when I'm trying to run library project.